# Conditional “#pragma omp critical {"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, openmp, c-preprocessor

So I want to do something like this

```
#ifdef MYCOND
#define CR_BEGIN #pragma omp critical{
#define CR_END }
#else
#define CR_BEGIN 
#define CR_END 
#endif
```

GCC (4.8.2) does not like line 2 one bit, due to the hashtag. A related question here at SO gives the answer "use _Pragma("")" but it does not work in this case.

Suggestions?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem when playing with OpenCL.  You cannot use `#pragma` in macro definitions.  Period.  You can, however, do `#ifdef MYCOND [newline] #pragma omp critical { [newline] #endif`, but you'll need to put it wherever it's needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

start_critical.h:

```
#ifdef MYCOND
#pragma omp critical{
#endif
```

end_critical.h

```
#ifdef MYCOND
}
#endif
```

And then use it like this:

```
#include "start_critical.h"
//sometimes critical code here
#include "end_critical.h"
```

Since there are no header guards in `start_critical.h` or `end_critical.h` you can use them as many times as you need to in any file.

Comment: Nice! It is a little bit more obscure, but at least it is an oneliner in the main file, and works as the code example intended.

Comment: This has to have the brace on the next line after critical, or it won't compile.